# JCR Modeshape - How is the repository storage structure in hard?

Tags: jcr, modeshape

I have some node and a folder node contain file nodes in my repository. My repository directory path is:
\home\myStorage\myRepository.
When I browse the repository directory, it contains some unknown files like this name: "-5597184", and some folders like these names: 0d , 0b , .... That I think these are my folder nodes. But sometimes these folders created out of myRepository directory! I don't know why!? but there is no problem in my application. 
 1. I just want to know why this happens? While the path for adding node is correct!

And the folders that I think are my node folders are too nested!  I mean they are folder in folder in folder , like this path: **/0b/95/46/fileName.pdf**. 
2. Why are they so?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're using ModeShape 3.x. In that case, you've likely configured the repository to store the binary content in that directory.

In that case, ModeShape stores binary values keyed by the SHA-1 hash of the bytes, in a directory structured defined by various parts of the SHA-1 hash (which is nicely distributed). For details, see [our documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Binary+values).

BTW, that is just the binary value storage. Your indexes and Infinispan storage should be elsewhere; if not, your configuration needs to be corrected. If you have any questions, ask them on [our user forums](https://community.jboss.org/en/modeshape/content).

Comment: Yes, I'm using ModeShape 3.2.0 . Thanks for your documentation. Interesting storage mechanism.